# How to make below bootstrap div structure with rotation title

Tags: user-interface, dashboard

[I want to create this dashboard using bootstrap divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2HpK.png)

Can anyone help me to create div structure.

I have used so many div structures but not able to make it possible.

Please let me know if you need any html structure, so I will try to provide.

Thank you